# Numpy: preserving dtype after column_stack()

Tags: python, numpy

*python3, numpy1.10*

Let's say, I have something like

`some_array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
bool_array = numpy.array([False for x in range(len(parts_array))], dtype='bool_')`

Then `bool_array` will be `[False, False, False]` and with `bool` type.

And when I do 
`another_array = numpy.column_stack((some_array, bool_array))`, both types become `str`, which I don't want to.
*What I want is preserving `bool` type in the second column*. I don't care about type of the first column.

Will I need to create another array? Seems like the solution is to pass the `dtype` like in [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html#structured-arrays), but I'd like to not copy the whole array generated by `column_stack()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have multiple data types in one numpy array. You might want to try a pandas data frame for example if you have

```
  some_array=['a','b','c']
  bool_array=[False, False, Fale]
```

you can define a data frame

```
 df=pd.DataFrame(bool_array, index=some_array.tolist(), columns=[1])
```

This will like like

```
    1
 a  False
 b  False
 c  False
```

the bool_array will keep its type but you will have to use data frame operations to access and manipulate it

Comment: I think it is possible to have multiple data type in one numpy array. It will have a type of object. You can simply try with a df with float and string as columns and then perform df.values to get a single numpy array that will have both type

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 (main) ways of adding values to a structured array - with a list of tuples or by copying values to each field.

e.g. by field:

```
In [368]: arr=np.zeros((3,),dtype='S10,bool')
In [369]: arr
Out[369]: 
array([(b'', False), (b'', False), (b'', False)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S10'), ('f1', '?')])
In [371]: arr['f0']=['one','two','three']
In [372]: arr['f1']=[True,False,True]
In [373]: arr
Out[373]: 
array([(b'one', True), (b'two', False), (b'three', True)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S10'), ('f1', '?')])
```

If you have a list of sublists, you'll need to convert the sublists to tuples:

```
In [378]: alist=[['one',True],['two',False],['three',True]]
In [379]: np.array([tuple(i) for i in alist], dtype=arr.dtype)
Out[379]: 
array([(b'one', True), (b'two', False), (b'three', True)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S10'), ('f1', '?')])
```

The `column_stack` won't help as an intermediate array, since it has lost the original column dtypes.

You could also explore functions in `from numpy.lib import recfunctions`.  That module has functions to merge arrays.  But the ones I have looked at use the field copy method, so they won't save any time.

```
In [381]: recfunctions.merge_arrays([['one','two','three'],[False,True,False]])
Out[381]: 
array([('one', False), ('two', True), ('three', False)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '?')])
```

Comment: I've currently remade this through `recarray`: `array = np.rec.fromarrays((some_array, bool_array), names=('keys', 'tf_value'))`. And it preserves both types. And works like a usual `ndarray`. Or it doesn't? I haven't spotted the difference between `ndarray` and `recarray`.

Comment: I haven't used them much, but as best I can tell `recarray` is just a subclass with a modified `__getattribute__` method.  `fromarrays` uses the copy by fields method I outlined (look at its code).